# Validate Mobile Number

Tags: validation, mobile, webforms, sms

I want to have a mobile number validate for my site not just string validations ..what i need is to actually validate the mobile number with the same user exists..

one option i know is to send a pin to that mobile number & ask user to put that pin on form submit to validate ...so are there any ready to use services for this to use it on my website or what i have to do for this ...

Also tell if you know any other options available

Answer (score 3):

You could use http://www.twilio.com/ to call the number and have the person respond (press 1 for ok, 0 for not ok) to your call.

But note that calling the number would work if the number was either a land-line or mobile. If you want to make sure that the number is mobile, then SMS is a good idea.

Twilio has an SMS api too.

Comment: Calling to a numbers could be SPAM, you should be careful. You are breaking many data protections laws.

Comment: @fravelgue: I disagree; supply a source for your claim. This technique of automated phone calls for verification is already done by banks. If you get a lot of "0" responses, indicating that someone was using your system to send spam, then you could require a captcha. The issues for calling / messaging someone to verify a supplied address are the same as for sending an email to verify a supplied address.

Comment: providing you make it clear to your user that entering their number will cause a validation message, then it is not spam; remember the user is filling in their number here, with the specific intention of using your service.  Don't forget though, landlines can send and recieve SMS too.

Answer (score 1):

you can use this service that give you web service that you can use to validate mobile number in any country http://www.data-8.co.uk/integr8/services/mobile_validation.aspx#Demo

Answer (score 0):

Some push agregattors have APIs for HLR-look up, then you could know if number is right and it is active or off, etc.

Answer (score 0):

If it's not super important that someone can fake their confirmation, then you could look at some of the headers received from the network operator containing the user's number:  [Can a mobile web application access the devices phone number?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3915852/can-a-mobile-web-application-access-the-devices-phone-number/7738711#7738711)