# Get unique, static id from a device via web request

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, c#-4.0

I have an MVC application that I would like to add some custom stats to.  For some of the stats, it would be nice to have a unique identifier for a device.

For example, if I have a unique id for a RSS subscriber, I can monitor the active number of RSS subscribers.

I was wondering if anyone knew of anything in the web request that could be used as an ID other than the IP (which can obviously change).  Something like a device ID or something?

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit more? You want to track each device that hits your web server? Just for RSS or also for web requests?  Are cookies an option?

Comment: I just wanted to know if there is a unique, non-changing identifier for a device that is accessible in the web request that the server receives.  Something like             Request.Browser.Id?  I'm not sure what the best property is to use for this.

Comment: It seems most of the "answers" here didn't really answer your question other than saying you can't do it, which is kind of the against the point of a question which is to find an *answer*. Check out my answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6445472/get-unique-static-id-from-a-device-via-web-request/7645461#7645461

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Here are some approaches to consider.

## HTTP Headers

There are a few HTTP Headers you can look at that can help you identify a unique user or device - some would refer to the sim card, some refer to the device.
Here is a list that I derived from the headers that Google Adsense Mobile uses to help track their advertising:

- `x-dcmguid`
- `x-up-subno`
- `x-jphone-uid`
- `x-em-uid`

These are probably some very popular one's, but there would be more vendor/device specific headers that are popular.  You could start gathering all the headers your site receives and count how many of each you receive and start building up your own database of common headers.

## Some other approaches

### Cookies

Cookies is something that can be set on the requesting agent (browser for example) and returned when the agent visits again.  For a list of methods, check out [Ever Cookie](http://samy.pl/evercookie/) - the virtually permanent cookie - it works by using one of the following methods of which at least one will work:

> ```
>  - Standard HTTP Cookies 
>  - Local Shared Objects (Flash Cookies)
>  - Silverlight Isolated Storage 
>  - Storing cookies in RGB values of auto-generated, force-cached 
>     PNGs using HTML5 Canvas tag to read pixels (cookies) back out
>  - Storing cookies in Web History 
>  - Storing cookies in HTTP ETags 
>  - Storing cookies in Web cache 
>  - window.name caching
>  - Internet Explorer userData storage
>  - HTML5 Session Storage 
>  - HTML5 Local Storage 
>  - HTML5 Global Storage 
>  - HTML5 Database Storage via SQLite
> ```

### Combinations

It's also possible to come up with your own scheme, e.g. take the `user-agent` header, some other headers like `accept`, `x-fowarded-for` and the ip make a unique hash value of out them to more accurately determine the uniqueness of the agent.

There are [many different mobile headers as seen here](http://mobiforge.com/developing/blog/useful-x-headers).  I also hit a page of mine and store mobile headers from various devices for my own purposes here http://wap.defza.com/ua/ua.txt (also ua1.txt, ua2.txt etc)

Answer (score 4):

The short answer is their isn't any (and with good reason given privacy concerns). The more helpful answer would be that this is something you would normally do using [cookies](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178194.aspx). You set a cookie and then check that to identify the specific browser making the request.

Of course, this is by no means fool-proof as users can reject cookies, delete them and they can use many different browsers (each of which will have a different cookie). If you are being devious (and I wouldn't recommend this) you could use a [Local Shared Object](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Local_Shared_Object) (Flash Cookie) as this is less likely to be removed. At the end of the day, though, if someone doesn't want to be tracked you can't force them to be.

Generally, though, if you want analytics and tracking then consider using a 3rd party solution like [Google Analytics](http://www.google.com/analytics/). This will give you very detailed data (albeit still relying on cookies and javascript) about your visitors and their browsing habits.

Answer (score 1):

> other than the IP

If your site doesn't require any sort of authentication in order to serve this content, the IP address is the only thing you could get to identify clients, and even this might not be unique, for example you could have two clients behind the same proxy => no way of distinguishing those requests in this case. Another possibility is to use cookies, but that sort of falls in the first category => authentication.

Comment: I beg to differ, if the client comes from mobile device, you can get the unique ids for that device which stays the same over the web for that device.

Answer (score 1):

There is no identifier that's provided by a browser, privacy concerns make it very unlikely that any vendor would ever implement that, now at least.

The only option you have is some form of cookie.

For RSS feeds, you could conceivably embed a random unique ID in the feed URL every time its rendered, so you'd know when the person that retrieved that URL downloaded your feed. However, if the user shared that URL with others you'd have no real way of knowing.